# c# asp.net delete last comma

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc, razor

I want to output in json format this loop

```
 [{  



@foreach (var urun in Model.urunler.Where(u => u.Id == item.uid).ToList())
        {
            <text>,"id":"@item.id","urunadi":"@urun.urunadi"</text>
        }



 },] delete this last comma
```

i want to output :
[{},{},{}] delete this last character

Comment: Not really clear what you are asking.......

Comment: i want to delete this  last comma.

Comment: Provide input please, what is "this"?

Comment: Still not clear. Is this text from a text file you are reading or is this source code?

Comment: I want to output in json format this loop

Comment: Can you add the actual output to your question

Answer (score 4):

Don't build the JSON manually. Instead, build an object graph, and then JSON-encode it:

```
@{
    var data = Model.urunler.Where(u => u.Id = item.uid).Select(u => new
    {
        id = item.id,
        urunadi = urun.urunadi
    });
}
@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(data))
```

Comment: There are 3 foreach loops inside.

Comment: Doesn't matter. Build the whole thing as an object graph, and then JSON-encode the whole thing. Trying to manually write JSON in Razor is just ridiculous.